# Google Sheets query formula to get last 25 items that have been run

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm using the formula below to try to generate a list, from another tab, in a Google Sheet. The aim is to pull out the last 25 times something was built.

I want the value for cell B2 to be something that a user can enter.  The value is going to be a text value such as `ABCDE1231535FGH`.

```
=QUERY('Line 10'!A:F,"select B,C,F where C = '\"T(B2)"\'  ORDER BY B DESC  LIMIT 25",3)""
```

I am getting `#ERROR!` message back.

[sample of what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxiHw.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pls share the sample spreadsheet or screen shot with desire result

Comment: the formula with the actual text is "select B,C, F WHERE C = 'LFSYS7009934PWR' ORDER BY B DESC  LIMIT 25"

Comment: If you want to refer cell B2 use `'"&B2&"'` but based on your screenshot Column selection is incorrect i believe `ORDER BY B` is given but Column B is empty, It would be better if you share sample sheet and what you want to achieve

Comment: *"based on your screenshot ..... share sample sheet and what you want to achieve"* @Shiva is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869796/google-sheets-query-formula-to-get-last-25-items-that-have-been-run#comment109435158_61869796) you can use the following syntax:

```
=QUERY(A10:F, "select B, C, F WHERE C = ' "& B2 &" ' ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 25")
```

Notice the use of the single quotes `'`, double quotes `"` and ampersand `&` when referring a cell.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I was able to get it to work.